# Scala, Quill, Postgres - cannot insert into database because of an "ON CONFLICT" error

Tags: sql, postgresql, scala, quill

I have a simple schema which creates table in Postgres:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test.table
(
    id     varchar(255)   NOT NULL,
    action varchar(255)   NOT NULL,
    text   varchar(255)   NOT NULL,
    

    PRIMARY KEY (id, action),
    CONSTRAINT fk_other FOREIGN KEY (id, action) REFERENCES test.others(action, id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

And a scala code which insert data into it:

```
testTable
        .insert(lift(entity))
        .onConflictUpdate(_.action, _.id)(
          (t, e) => t.text -> e.text
        .returning[TestRow](r => r)
```

But when I ran it, I got an error:
`Message, there is no unique or exclusion constraint matching the ON CONFLICT specification`

I think I have done everything well here, but this error seems strange. Can you help me with that?

Comment: Do you ACTUALLY have that primary key or unique constraint in db?
I only can reproduce that behaviour when there isn't.

Comment: Check your `column` name mappings. And check the generated query.

Comment: Thanks for help. I fixed it. The problem was with my deployment, not with code. The structure is good, but method `.onConflictUpdate(_.action, _.id)` needs to have exactly same arguments as `PRIMARY KEY (id, action)` - so if someone have similar problem, that could be an asnwer.

Answer (score 0):

Your `INSERT INTO ... ON CONFLICT` statement is missing the `unique or exclusion constraint` thats required to determine how the inserted row can conflict with an existing row in the table.

This may be due to the automatic inference not finding your constraint, or the more likely case that you have forgotten to specify one or more columns that identify the constraint.

In SQL, you can explicitly specify the constraint like this:

```sql
INSERT INTO distributors (did, dname)
VALUES (9, 'Antwerp Design')
ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT distributors_pkey
DO NOTHING;
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, and thanks for trying to help by adding your answer. But please, try to understand the question and then try to provide relevant answers. Do not copy-paste seemingly related but non-relevant content from other blogs - https://pganalyze.com/docs/log-insights/app-errors/U125